# Right click contextMenu on QPushButton

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, contextmenu, pyqt4

For my app I have created a GUI in Qt Designer and converted it into python(2.6) code.

On some of the `QPushButton` (created with the designer) I want to add a right click context menu. The menu options depend on the application status.

How to implement such a context menu ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check if an example below would work for you. The key thing is to [set context menu policy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop) for your widget to CustomContextMenu and connect to the widget's [customContextMenuRequested](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) signal:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)

        # create button
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("test button", self)       
        self.button.resize(100, 30)

        # set button context menu policy
        self.button.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.button.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_context_menu)

        # create context menu
        self.popMenu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
        self.popMenu.addAction(QtGui.QAction('test0', self))
        self.popMenu.addAction(QtGui.QAction('test1', self))
        self.popMenu.addSeparator()
        self.popMenu.addAction(QtGui.QAction('test2', self))        

    def on_context_menu(self, point):
        # show context menu
        self.popMenu.exec_(self.button.mapToGlobal(point))        

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi Serge, Thanks for your reply. It seems to soleve my issue. rgds Arthur.

Comment: if it solves your issue, pls, mark your question as answered, regards

Comment: TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType' on self.popMenu.addAction(QtGui.QAction('test0', self))