# How to get a QDialog QlineEdit window to output to QtableWidgetCell?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt

I'm new to both Python and PyQT4.

I have this simple QDialog Box with a QlineEdit in it.

```
class Ui_UserCode(object):
def setupUi(self, UserCode):
    UserCode.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("UserCode"))
    UserCode.resize(265, 125)
    UserCode.setMouseTracking(False)
    self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(UserCode)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 50, 151, 31))
    self.lineEdit.setFrame(True)
    self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.lineEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("returnPressed()")), UserCode.insertUC)
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(UserCode)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 20, 151, 20))
    self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
    self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(UserCode)
    self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 90, 180, 32))
    self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal) self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
    self.buttonBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonBox"))

    self.retranslateUi(UserCode)

    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("accepted()")), UserCode.accept)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("rejected()")), UserCode.reject)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(UserCode)

def retranslateUi(self, UserCode):
    UserCode.setWindowTitle(_translate("UserCode", "Dialog", None))
    self.label.setText(_translate("UserCode", "Please Enter User Code", None))
    self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("Dialog", "", None))
```

And this line of code in a separate Class for a QtableWidget I have created.

```
  item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "" , None))
```

And then... my **init** Classes and  pyqtSlot()

```
 class StartUC(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
    QDialog.__init__(self)
    self.uc = Ui_UserCode()
    self.uc.setupUi(self)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()

@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def insertUC(self):
    inputNumber = self.uc.lineEdit.text()
    tableWidget = StartMain(QTableWidgetItem)
    item = tableWidget.item(0, 1)
    tableWidget.item.setText("MainWindow", "%s"% inputNumber, None)

class StartMain(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
       self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
       self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

My Questions are how do I get the QlineEdit of the dialog box to populate the QtableWidgetCell on a returnPressed event? Is my pyqtSlot() method even in the right place? I realize I've still got lots to learn so if someone could point in the right direction that would be awesome. The PyQT documentation gave me a decent start but I'm not sure how to finish this...

Comment: put `print "I am here"` as first line of `insertUC(self)` so you'll know if pyqtSlot() method is in the right place. Also your `setText` has 3 inputs, it's suppose to have one: 
`void QTableWidgetItem::setText ( const QString & text )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at code that I wrote for this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/18447504/1155106

You can run it, it does some simple things so you can see how to use slots and signals and pass signal from class to class.

I hope it helps.